# printing div content with css applied

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I am working on a project and I want to print div content.The code which I am using is fulfilling my requirements,but I am getting simple output without Css applied to it and also not getting the image.Please help me.I am attaching the code and output I am getting and output I want.

Code:

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
    Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'new div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/midday_receipt.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Output I am getting before clicking print button:
[image]

Output I am getting by clicking print button:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle or the associated HTML source code that we can reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Sharing some HTML and CSS would be better. a http://jsfiddle.net would be even greater. Are you using media attribute inside style tag?

Answer (score 19):

If you wanna render the CSS you must add a timeout before printing it because it takes some time for CSS to be applied to the HTML and then you will be able to print it.

Try this:

```
function Popup(data) {
      var mywindow = window.open('', 'new div', 'height=400,width=600');
      mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
      mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/midday_receipt.css" type="text/css" />');
      mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
      mywindow.document.write(data);
      mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
      mywindow.document.close();
      mywindow.focus();
      setTimeout(function(){mywindow.print();},1000);
      mywindow.close();

      return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I almost went crazy with this until I added the timeout.

Comment: The new window just closes instantly. Fix it with following.
setTimeout(function(){
    mywindow.print(); 
    mywindow.close();
   },1000);

Answer (score 12):

You need to change the css property `media` to `print`.
Add new line to your function createPopup() as below you attached your css:

```
mywindow.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\"/>" );
```

Comment: Note, when media="print" was used, it did prevent the CSS to be applied on the html rendered in the new window. Instead I had to use media="all"

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion is to add to the `<body>` tag some javascript to do the printing and closing.

`<body onload="window.print();window.close()">`

Doing this will always allow enough time for the document and the CSS to load before the print window opens, and then closes the window immediately after the print dialogue closes.

Comment: This is the best answer, as opposed to waiting an arbitrary amount of time in the higher voted answers.

Comment: I'm using React and rendering the page to get passed into the popup window, `onLoad` isn't preserved for whatever reason. My solution was to add a `<script/>` tag after the body that has the print line in it. Same effect for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using image as background image of site you will definitely not get it, while printing browser disables all background images.

Try to use **img** tags instead. Also make sure in your browser disable images option is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the div to be printed, as an input to print function,

```
<input type='button' id='btn-print' value='Print Receipt' onclick="printDiv('#invoice-box-id');" />
```

Then clone the element,

```
function printDiv(elem)
{
   renderMe($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
}
```

Pass the cloned element to render, include the stylesheet in it.

```
function renderMe(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'invoice-box', 'height=1000,width=1000');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>invoice-box</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="printstyle.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');


    setTimeout(function () {
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    }, 1000)
    return true;
}
```

> If innerHTML is passed, it will ignore the styles.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause of your rendering issue may be due to the relative paths you're using for the CSS file and images. First, try to use absolute paths. The fact that the HTML structure is rendered excludes problems with the generation of the new HTML document. Also, add `media="print"`to the `link`element.

This code works, though partially:

```
    (function() {

function createPopup( data ) {
    var mywindow = window.open( "", "new div", "height=400,width=600" );
    mywindow.document.write( "<html><head><title></title>" );
    mywindow.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>" );
    mywindow.document.write( "</head><body >" );
    mywindow.document.write( data );
    mywindow.document.write( "</body></html>" );

    mywindow.print();
    //mywindow.close();

    return true;

}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById( "print" ).addEventListener( "click", function() {
        createPopup( document.getElementById( "content" ).innerHTML );

    }, false );

});

   })();
```

I've removed the .close() call. Bear in mind that some CSS styles may not work with print.

Comment: I tried to use absolute path but got the same output as above

Comment: Give me some time. I'll get back with a demo. :-)

Comment: Here's my test: [Print window content](http://gabrieleromanato.name/tests/javascript/print-window-content/)

Answer (score 0):

```
       function printpage() {
           var getpanel = document.getElementById("<%= Panel1.ClientID%>");
           var MainWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=800');
           MainWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
           MainWindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles/Print.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>");
           MainWindow.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print();window.close()">');
           MainWindow.document.write(getpanel.innerHTML);
           MainWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
           MainWindow.document.close();
           setTimeout(function () {
               MainWindow.print();
           }, 500)
           return false;
```

}

Comment: Please avoid code only answers and try to describe, how this code can help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I combined and had this working perfectly:

```
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');
    mywindow.document.write("<link href=\"../lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link href=\"../css/core.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link href=\"../css/components.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link href=\"../css/icons.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">")
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('printit').innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/


    setTimeout(function () {
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    }, 1000)
    return true;
}
```