# JavaScript print div with CSS-Style

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site where I want to generate a PDF, for this, I have created a page where there is a DIV from which the PDF should be generated. I used this link to help, but for me, it breaks right after pressing the button.

[printing div content with css applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379605/printing-div-content-with-css-applied/44820290)

If I delete the following line it works but then the PDF is no longer styled.
(Since it's on WordPress, I have a parenting style and a custom CSS both are valid linked in functions.php)

In the gif, you can see that I first try to print the page but it doesn't work. in the second s scene, I print again and it works but without CSS.

I the first scene, I have the link and the timeout in it, and in the second scene I have both commented out.

(https://im6.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-6-54e1daed3b61.gif)

My Code:

```js
function PrintElem() {

    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Offerte', 'height=297mm,width=210mm');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    // mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="./print.css" type="text/css">');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('A4').innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();

    mywindow.print();

    // setTimeout(function(){mywindow.print();},1000);
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

```css
@media print {
    .A4 {
        width: 210mm;
        height:297mm;
        border: solid 1px black;
        left: 50% -105mm;
    }

    .pdfExport {
        margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 20mm;
        /* border: solid 1px black; */
    }

    .tableRechnung {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: solid 1px black;
        width: 100%
    }
}

@media screen {
    .A4 {
        width: 210mm;
        height:297mm;
        border: solid 1px black;
        left: 50% -105mm;
    }

    .pdfExport {
        margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 20mm;
        /* border: solid 1px black; */
    }

    .tableRechnung {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: solid 1px black;
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="A4" id='A4'>
            <div class='pdfExport'>
                <div class='offerteLogo'>
                    <img src="https://example.ch/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Web-1920-–-17.png" alt="img" width="200px" height="auto">
                </div>
                <div class='offerteAdresse'>
                    <p>
                    John Doe Company <br>
                    Company AG <br>
                    Street 30 <br>
                    1234 City <br>
                    <a href="tel:0012 345 67 89">0012 345 67 89</a><br>
                    <a href="mailto:john.doe@company.com">john.doe@company.com</a><br>
                    <a href="https://company.com">https://company.com</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class='offerteTitel'>
                    <h4>Offerte</h4><br>
                </div>
                <div class='offerteEinleitungsText'>
                    <p>
                        Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren<br>
                        Vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage, wir unterbreiten Ihnen gerne das gewünschte Angebot. Wir freuen uns auf Ihren Auftrag.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class='offerteAuflistung'>
                    <table class='tableRechnung'>
                        <!-- <thead> -->
                            <!-- <th> -->
                                <td>Leistung</td>
                                <td>Anzahl</td>
                                <td>à</td>
                                <td>Beitrag in CHF</td>
                            <!-- </th> -->
                        <!-- </thead> -->
                        <tbody>
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class='offerteAusleitungsText'>
                    <p>
                        Bei fragen sind wir gerne für Sie da.<br><br>
                        Freundliche Grüsse <br>
                        John Doe
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <button onClick='PrintElem()'>Drucken</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open a blank window with `window.open('', ...` it will not be linked to your WP styles - all CSS you need in that window you need to link by hand with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..."/>` written in that window.

Another approach to print your div without even opening new window is to add to your html something like this:

```
<button class="printButton" onClick='window.print()'>Drucken</button>
<style>
  @media print {
    .printButton,
    .CLASS-OR-OTHER-SELECTOR-TO-MATCH-YOUR-ORANGE-TOP-BAR,
    .ANYTHING-ELSE-THAT-YOU-DONT-WANT-ON-YOUR-PRINTOUT {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

It will make your button to print the current page styled as it is with modified only that CSS as stated in that media print (hidden top bar, print button or anything else you want to hide - just modify/add selectors to your needs)

Comment: With the style tag in the HTML it works without problems, but now I have to style everything myself. How could I include the default theme from WordPress if I can't just add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css">` tag in the HTML div.